# How does recursion through variable return an increasign order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

This logic and output seem counter-intuitive, can someone explain this logic descriptively?

```js
function countdown(n){
  if(n < 1){
    return [];
  }
  else{
    const countArray = countdown(n-1)
    countArray.push(n);
    return countArray;
  }
}
console.log(countdown(5));
```

Comment: You want explanation of code?

Comment: Try adding `console.log(countArray)` after the initial assignment `const countArray = countdown(n-1)` and you will see what is happening.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to understand the output evaluation. Does recursion perform differently over here?

Comment: @Nick An empty array gets assigned to countArray, but how does the value increment ? Shouldn't it exit the function after pushing the '1' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to understand recursion is to think about it like mathematical induction.  In induction, we show that a statement is true for all positive integers by showing that it's true for `n = 1`, and that if it's true for all values less than a given `n`, then it's true for `n`.  These two facts are enough to show that it's true for all `n`s.

To understand a recursive function, we need to show that the base case does what we expect and that *if the smaller cases are true*, then it's true for the current case.  Then we know it's true for all cases.  Occasionally it will be tricky to decide what's a smaller case, but usually it's straightforward, as it is here.

Let's try this understanding of recursion on your function.  But first, let's note that there's a naming problem.  The function we're trying to describe does not `count down`, it `counts up`.  A function called `countDown` would presumably, on given `5` count down from there, returning `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`.  Yours counts up, yielding `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.  You were asking for an explanation of how this one works, I think, not asking how to get the countdown working.  If you are looking for that, please ask a separate question.  But I will assume you mean `countUp`, and will use this variant in the discussion below:

```js
function countUp(n){
  if(n < 1){
    return [];
  }
  else{
    const countArray = countUp(n-1)
    countArray.push(n);
    return countArray;
  }
}
```

First we have a base case:

```js
  if(n < 1){
    return [];
  }
```

if `n` is less than 1, then there are no numbers to count down, so the empty array is the correct response.

Now, we make an assumption: We assume that the recursion works for all values less than our current `n`.  If we can show that it is then true on our current `n`, we've shown that it's true for all `n`s`.

Now we have

```js
  else{
    const countArray = countUp(n-1)
    countArray.push(n);
    return countArray;
  }
```

This line is the important one:

```js
    const countArray = countUp(n-1)
```

We have made the assumption that our recursion works for smaller versions of `n`.  So we can assume that `countUp(n-1)` yields `[1, 2, 3, ..., (n - 1)]`.  Then we call `countArray.push(n)`, so that now equals `[1, 2, 3, ..., (n - 1), n]`, which is just as we wanted.  We return that value and we're done.

We have just demonstrated that for every positive `n`, `countUp(n)` yields `[1, 2, 3, ..., n]`.

If it helps you to be more concrete, we can look at the case, `n = 5`.  The test `n < 1` fails so we go the `else` block, where we call `countUp(4)`.  But we've already assumed that one worked, so we know that it will return `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.  We push `5` onto this array and return the result, giving back `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`  While we could of course push this further and note that in generating `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, we first call `countUp(3)`, yielding `[1, 2, 3]` and then pushing `4`, and that to get that we call `countUp(2)`, yielding `[1, 2]`, etc.  But that will show only that it works for `5`.  It's a useful exercise sometimes, but to truly understand this, you can go beyond the specific case and work with the assumption I suggest and see how that shows the recursion working.

---

We can use this technique in *writing* a recursive function as well.  Here we write a different version of the same function, using our technique explicitly.

We want a recursive function that, given a positive integer `n`, returns the array `[1, 2, 3, ..., n]`.  So for our base case, we can choose several options.  We could check if `n == 1` and return `[1]`.  We could if we wanted check if `n == 2` and return `[1, 2]`, but then that wouldn't work for `n == 1`.  But a simpler one would be what happens if `n < 1`.  In that case we want to return an empty array.  So we can start with a conditional expression:

```js
const countUp = (n) =>
  n < 1 
    ? [] 
    : /* now what goes here? */
```

Well, we can make the assumption that our function already works for anything less than `n`, so we can assume that it works for `n - 1`, and `countUp(n - 1)` will yield `[1, 2, 3, ..., (n - 1)]`.  Well, to turn that into `[1, 2, 3, ..., (n - 1), n]` only takes concatenating `n` onto the end of the previous call.  We can write it like this:

```js
const countUp = (n) =>
  n < 1 
    ? [] 
    : countUp(n - 1).concat(n)
```

Or, using more modern JS, as

```js
const countUp = (n) =>
  n < 1 
    ? [] 
    : [...countUp(n - 1), n]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const countArray = countdown(n-1)
countArray.push(n);
```

Since you are calling countdown(n-1) before pushing n to array, countdown(n-1) evaluates first.

```
   function countdown(n,countArray ){
     if(n < 1){
       return [];
     }
      else{
        countArray.push(n);
        countdown(n-1,countArray);
        return countArray;
      }
    }
    console.log(countdown(5,[]));
```

Output of this will be [5,4,3,2,1]

Comment: This does not explain the output. Since the value gets evaluated once, shouldn't the output of the code I have attached be [1] ?

Comment: [1] returns to the countdown(2) function call at const countArray = countdown(n-1) then countArray.push(n);
return countArray;
evaluates and returns [1,2] to countdown(3) function call at const countArray = countdown(n-1)

Comment: In recursion once you call the function it gets added to top of the call stack and Last function evaluates first and returns the output to next last.

In this case the call stack would be
countdown(1)
countdown(2)
countdown(3)
countdown(4)
countdown(5)

Answer (score 0):

Since it returns empty array `[]` as `countArray` function when `n < 1`, n can be pushed into countArray. Before 1 is pushed array `countArray` function is executed as `countdown(n-1)`. 2 is pushed on array `[1]` and function's recurred to `countdown(5)`.

```js
function countdown(n){
  if(n < 1){
    return [];
  }
  else{
    const countArray = countdown(n-1)
    countArray.push(n);
    return countArray;
  }
}
console.log(countdown(5));
```